# How do I read the contents of Windows History (folder) using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, filesystems

I want to read the contents of "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\History" using python. I tried `os.listdir`, but it just returned "History.IE5" and "Low". How do I read the names of all the items inside them and possibly delete them?

Answer (score 0):

You need os.walk

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('path\\to\\folder'):
    print(root)
    print(dirs)
    print(files)
    for file in files:
       os.remove(file)
```

Comment: When I tried to `print(file)` , It kept printing container.dat. Can I safely delete these?

Comment: I'm not sure, why do you want to delete them?

Comment: I'm writing a script to delete every kind of user history (file history and networking) and cache stored locally on my PC.